# Why are more powerful tools using higher voltage?

Tags: power, batteries

AFAIK each of the world leading cordless power tools manufacturers produces several "product lines" of cordless power tools with different voltages. For example, Bosch currently produces tools with Li-Ion batteries with 10,7V, 14,4V, 18V and 36V output and the higher the voltage the more powerful a tool is.

Now those tools are powered by batteries that are assembled from cells with lower voltage (something like 3,7 volts for Li-Ion cells I guess) and cells are connected in sequence until the target voltage is reached.

They could instead connect cells in parallel. They would have the same voltage, but higher current and that would again yield higher power.

Why do they choose higher voltage over same voltage and higher current to get higher power in electric tools?

Comment: We are not consumer electronics and we dropped our robotics. Closed as off-topic. 5 reopen votes can change that.

Comment: Voted to reopen. @Kortuk, you might not have closed this if Bosch tools weren't mentioned. It's a good question for EE IMO: why cells in series, and not parallel.

Comment: @Kortuk: Consumer electronics application is there as an example only. I can't see why it's not a pure electrical engineering question.

Comment: @Stevenvh, I thought that might be the case. It seems just motor related to me. I am find with that, you got 3 votes in no time, I will finish it.

Comment: Shouldn't the process be "wait for enough close votes to close" rather than "wait for enough reopen votes" after forcing it closed?

Comment: @endolith, This was a case of, "This looks clearly off-topic to me, but it is boundary, I will take a vote." Unless I am doing a merge of some sort nothing I do is permanent.

Comment: @Kortuk closing something is not taking a vote.  Taking a vote would be stating your personal opinion and casting (1) close vote yourself.  To say that what you do is "not permanent" misses the point - there's a huge "potential barrier" between something that is open until enough people decide to close it, vs. something that is closed until enough people decide to re-open it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I cannot cast a single close vote, ever. This has been requested but it has been decided that moderators only cast complete votes. Second, it may seem possible, but we do many many things a day and it is very easy to close and leave a comment which elicits immediate response compared to leaving a comment which asks opinion which will only sometimes elicit response. I read it again later when I had received responses and realized I had misread the question to some extent. I believe it is actually a duplicate of an earlier question about batteries.

Comment: The wording is wholly different but this is effectively why do you use series batteries over parallel. I will try to find a link later to share. Please feel free to contact me in chat if you would like to discuss this more.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/parallel-charger-circuits

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13773/how-should-i-connect-batteries-in-parallel

Comment: This question sure seems off-topic to me. If the OP was planning on building a device with motors and wanted to know why he should use higher voltage instead of batteries in parallel then he should have asked that. But since that is not what he asked, it is a consumer electronics question asked from a technical consumer perspective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Matt already explained that using a higher voltage you'll have a **lower current for the same power rating**. This means **thinner and less heavy wires**, which means savings (copper is expensive). You may have to pay attention to **better insulation**, but that doesn't outweigh the advantage mentioned.

It's also much **easier to place cells in series than parallel**. When placed in parallel the voltages have to be exactly equal, otherwise you'll have high currents running from one cell to the other, causing **big power losses** and **reducing the cell's life**.

Comment: +1 another reason, I would think, is the ease of building down converters from a higher voltage.

Comment: @kenny - compared to buck-boost converters, yes. Compared to boost converters, no. The latter are no more complicated than buck converters. And I think this is older than switchers, too.

Comment: Standard boost converters have one problem that buck, buck-boost, and SEPIC don't: they pass current to the load when the converter is **not** switching, preventing a simple shutdown function. In other news, all the **bold words** make it a tad **harder** to **read**. ;p

Comment: @Mike - I always use bold words to highlight key words, and I never had any complaints. I may have overdone it here a little. But then, yeah, life can be tough! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh I'm not questioning your answer, because I know from my experience this is true.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to demonstrate this mathematically.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: @stevenvh I actually managed to figure out what I was looking for.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @stevenvh, With a drill though the reason is motor related. If you want higher torque out of your motor you use higher voltage. They are not adding batteries to save pennies on wires in a drill. The idea is crazy. You are using the higher voltage so that your drill has more power at getting that stuck bolt out!

Comment: The second paragraph makes absolutely no sense. If you bring your cells to the same voltage before connecting them, this would never be a problem and actually less of a problem because from then on, their voltage will never be different. Even if you connect them with a different voltage initially, the impairment is a one-time hit. Cells with different voltage in series kills cells every charge/discharge cycle because you're overvoltaging some and undervoltaging others. If a perfectly efficient boost converter were possible, all cells in parallel would be ideal for battery longevity.

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: Higher voltage is needed for higher rpm.

I disagree with copper efficiency argument (above/below)

The only reason is back EMF of motors at high rpm. No matter how much current the batteries can supply, their current translates to torque for motor, but not velocity. At top velocity, theoretical lossless motor has back emf exactly equal to the voltage of supply and consumes current approaching zero while having zero torque.

Higher power tools perhaps have higher rpm, rotational velocity figures, and they need higher voltage.

Comment: I like this answer.  If you think about copper then less current = less magnetic force, you make up for this with more turns.  I think the total mass of copper stays about the same.  Even RPM can be addressed thru gearing, I think most tools gear down.

Comment: I checked with Bosch Professional Tools site - RPM is not very different for different product lines. The reason is very high RPM is useless - driving screws is plain impossible at very high RPM and drilling produces lots of heat that damages both the material and the drill bit.

Answer (score 5):

For exactly the same reason the power companies transmit power around the country at many hundreds of thousands of volts instead of just doing it all at 110/230v.

A higher voltage means a lower current for the same amount of power.

A lower current means smaller components and thinner wires, thus making it cheaper and more efficient.

For example, take a DC motor.

For a 12V motor to develop the same amount of power as a 24V motor it would have to draw twice as much current.  This would mean that the windings in the motor would have to be made up of thicker wire.  This would increase both size and cost.

The electricity companies transfer power at a high voltage so the current is low so they can use small diameter cables.  It's all the same principle.

Answer (score 3):

The higher is the voltage, the lower is the current, at same power. When you suck lot of current from a battery, you'll create a poorly changed area inside. That leads to a worse performance.

Comment: I can't see why this is a problem. I have many cells in parallel now, so although I drain more from the pack I still drain the same from each cell.

Comment: @sharptooth - placing cells in parallel is not a good idea, see [my answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17190/why-are-more-powerful-tools-using-higher-voltage/17193#17193)